# not-null property references a null or transient value

Tags: java, html, jsf

Quando tento salvar alguma cidade, mostra erro de not-null, porém olhando, não consigo achar uma solução ao olhar pelo controller, entendo o erro, mas no meu projeto.

> Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : com.pi.drogaria.model.entidades.Cidade.estado

Model:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int codigoCidade;

@Column(length = 50, nullable = false)
private String nome;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(nullable = false)
private Estado estado;

public int getCodigoCidade() {
    return codigoCidade;
}

public void setCodigoCidade(int codigoCidade) {
    this.codigoCidade = codigoCidade;
}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

public Estado getEstado() {
    return estado;
}

public void setEstado(Estado estado) {
    this.estado = estado;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + codigoCidade;
    result = prime * result + ((estado == null) ? 0 : estado.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((nome == null) ? 0 : nome.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Cidade other = (Cidade) obj;
    if (codigoCidade != other.codigoCidade)
        return false;
    if (estado == null) {
        if (other.estado != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!estado.equals(other.estado))
        return false;
    if (nome == null) {
        if (other.nome != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!nome.equals(other.nome))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

XHMTL:

```
<ui:define name="conteudo">

    <h:form id="formListagem">

        <p:panel header="Cidades - Listagem">

            <p:dataTable id="tabela" emptyMessage="Nenhum registro encontrado."
                paginator="true" value="#{cidadeController.cidades}" var="cidade"
                rows="5" paginatorPosition="top">

                <f:facet name="header">

                    <p:commandButton value="Novo" actionListener="#{cidadeController.novo()}"
                        oncomplete="PF('dialogo').show();"
                        update=":mensagem :formCadastro:painel">

                        <f:actionListener
                            type="org.omnifaces.eventlistener.ResetInputAjaxActionListener" />

                    </p:commandButton>

                </f:facet>

                <p:column headerText="Nome" filterBy="#{cidade.nome}"
                    sortBy="#{cidade.nome}">

                    <h:outputText value="#{cidade.nome}" />

                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Estado" filterBy="#{cidade.estado.nome}"
                    sortBy="#{cidade.estado.nome}">

                    <h:outputText value="#{cidade.estado.nome}" />

                    <h:outputText value=" - " />

                    <h:outputText value="#{cidade.estado.sigla}" />

                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Opções">

                    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash"
                        actionListener="#{cidadeController.excluir()}"
                        update=":mensagem :formListagem:tabela">

                        <p:confirm header="Confirmação" message="Deseja excluir a cidade"
                            icon="ui-icon-alert" />

                        <f:attribute name="cidadeSelecionada" value="#{cidade}" />

                    </p:commandButton>

                    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-pencil"
                        actionListener="#{cidadeController.editar()}"
                        update=":mensagem :formCadastro:painel"
                        oncomplete="PF('dialogo').show();">

                        <f:attribute name="cidadeSelecionada" value="#{cidade}" />

                        <f:actionListener
                            type="org.omnifaces.eventlistener.ResetInputAjaxActionListener" />

                    </p:commandButton>

                </p:column>

            </p:dataTable>

            <p:confirmDialog global="true">

                <p:commandButton value="Sim" type="button"
                    styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" />

                <p:commandButton value="Não" type="button"
                    styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" />

            </p:confirmDialog>

        </p:panel>

    </h:form>

    <p:dialog header="Cidades - Cadastro" widgetVar="dialogo"
        draggable="false" resizable="false" modal="true" closable="false">

        <h:form id="formCadastro">

            <h:panelGrid id="painel" columns="2">

                <p:outputLabel for="nome" value="Nome:" />

                <p:inputText id="nome" maxlength="50" size="30"
                    value="#{cidadeController.cidade.nome}" required="true"
                    requiredMessage="O campo NOME é obrigatório" />

                <p:outputLabel for="estado" value="Estado:" />

                <p:selectOneMenu id="estado" filter="true"
                    value="#{cidadeController.cidade.estado}"
                    converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter" required="true"
                    requiredMessage="O campo ESTADO é obrigatório">

                    <f:selectItem noSelectionOption="true"
                        itemLabel="Selecione um estado" />

                    <f:selectItems value="#{cidadeController.estados}" var="estado"
                        itemValue="#{estado}"
                        itemLabel="#{estado.nome} - #{estado.sigla}" />

                </p:selectOneMenu>

            </h:panelGrid>

            <h:panelGrid columns="2">

                <p:commandButton value="Salvar"
                    actionListener="#{cidadeController.salvar()}"
                    update=":mensagem :formCadastro:painel :formListagem:tabela" />

                <p:commandButton value="Fechar" oncomplete="PF('dialogo').hide();" />

            </h:panelGrid>

        </h:form>

    </p:dialog>
```

Erro Console:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : com.pi.drogaria.model.entidades.Cidade.estado
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:913)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:887)
at com.pi.drogaria.DAO.DAOGenerico.merge(DAOGenerico.java:137)
at com.pi.drogaria.model.entidades.CidadeModel.salvar(CidadeModel.java:22)
at com.pi.drogaria.controller.CidadeController.salvar(CidadeController.java:85)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:247)
at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:147)
at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:814)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:492)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1152)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1539)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1495)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : com.pi.drogaria.model.entidades.Cidade.estado
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Nullability.checkNullability(Nullability.java:108)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Nullability.checkNullability(Nullability.java:56)
at org.hibernate.action.internal.AbstractEntityInsertAction.nullifyTransientReferencesIfNotAlready(AbstractEntityInsertAction.java:115)
at org.hibernate.action.internal.AbstractEntityInsertAction.makeEntityManaged(AbstractEntityInsertAction.java:124)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:289)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:263)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:250)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:367)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:292)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:200)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:143)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.saveTransientEntity(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:255)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:235)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:173)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:69)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:901)
... 42 more
```

CidadeController:

```
public class CidadeController implements Serializable {
private Cidade cidade;
private List<Cidade> cidades;
private List<Estado> estados;

public Cidade getCidade() {
    return cidade;
}

public void setCidade(Cidade cidade) {
    this.cidade = cidade;
}

public List<Cidade> getCidades() {
    return cidades;
}

public void setCidades(List<Cidade> cidades) {
    this.cidades = cidades;
}

public List<Estado> getEstados() {
    return estados;
}

public void setEstados(List<Estado> estados) {
    this.estados = estados;
}

@PostConstruct
public void listar() {
    try {
        CidadeModel cidadeModel = new CidadeModel();

        this.setCidades(cidadeModel.listar());

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Messages.addFlashGlobalError("Ocorreu um erro ao tentar listar as cidades");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void novo() {
    try {
        cidade = new Cidade();

        EstadoDAO estadoDAO = new EstadoDAO();
        List<Object> estados = estadoDAO.listar("nome", Estado.class);

        List<Estado> states = getListEstado(estados);
        this.setEstados(states);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Messages.addFlashGlobalError("Ocorreu um erro ao gerar uma nova cidade");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void salvar() {
    try {
        CidadeModel cidadeModel = new CidadeModel();

        this.setCidades(cidadeModel.salvar(cidade));

        EstadoDAO estadoDAO = new EstadoDAO();
        List<Object> estados = estadoDAO.listar(Estado.class);

        List<Estado> states = getListEstado(estados);
        this.setEstados(states);

        cidade = new Cidade();

        Messages.addGlobalInfo("Cidade salva com sucesso");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Messages.addFlashGlobalError("Ocorreu um erro ao tentar salvar uma nova cidade");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private List<Estado> getListEstado(List<Object> estados) {
    List<Estado> states = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Object obj : estados) {
        states.add((Estado) obj);
    }
    return states;
}

private List<Cidade> getListCidade(List<Object> cidades) {
    List<Cidade> city = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Object obj : cidades) {
        city.add((Cidade) obj);
    }
    return city;
}

public void excluir(ActionEvent evento) {
    try {
        cidade = (Cidade) evento.getComponent().getAttributes().get("cidadeSelecionada");

        CidadeModel cidadeModel = new CidadeModel();
        this.setCidades(cidadeModel.excluir(cidade));

        Messages.addGlobalInfo("Cidade removida com sucesso");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Messages.addFlashGlobalError("Ocorreu um erro ao tentar remover a cidade");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void editar(ActionEvent evento) {
    try {
        cidade = (Cidade) evento.getComponent().getAttributes().get("cidadeSelecionada");

        CidadeModel cidadeModel = new CidadeModel();
        this.setCidades(cidadeModel.editar(cidade));

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Messages.addFlashGlobalError("Ocorreu um erro ao tentar selecionar uma cidade");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Vc viu se a entidade está com os valores setados corretamente antes de persistir (no `CidadeController.salvar`)?

Comment: @MarcusMartins eu acho que esta correto, eu coloquei meu CidadeController, para você ver se pode ajudar nisso.

Comment: Coloca um breakpoint na linha do `this.setCidades(cidadeModel.salvar(cidade))` para ver se o objeto `cidade` está com todos os valores setados. Estou achando que ele não está com o estado setado no momento de persistir. Pode ser bug no converter omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter.

Comment: @MarcusMartins coloquei e mesmo assim fica com esse erro "not-null property references a null or transient value : com.pi.drogaria.model.entidades.Cidade.estado"

Comment: Mas verificou se o objeto cidade está com todos os valores setados?

Comment: @MarcusMartins descobri o problema, é que toda vez que eu modificava algo no controller, meu projeto ou o eclipse, não atualizava as alterações, então, fiz um maven install e pegou... obrigado mesmo assim.

Answer (score 3):

Basicamente, você está chamando um persist na entidade Cidade que tem o atributo estado configurada como `nullable = false`, portanto, se você não definir esse atributo, o JPA / hibernate não permitirá que você salve-a no banco de dados.